# ViewChild vs Directive to get ViewContainerRef

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-components

I found that **[Angular Docs](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader)** suggest that in order to get access to the **`ViewContainerRef`** to create a dynamic component I should use a directive like:

```
import { Directive, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[ad-host]',
})
export class AdDirective {
  constructor(public viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef) { }
}
```

And later in the component:

```
export class AppComponent {  
  @ViewChild(AdDirective, {static: true}) adHost: AdDirective;

... //to get access to ViewContainerRef
const viewContainerRef = this.adHost.viewContainerRef;
```

However, I could achieve the same without the directive by using **`ViewChild`** with `{read : ViewContainerRef}` like:

```
export class AppComponent {

  @ViewChild('someHashTag', {read : ViewContainerRef}) target: ViewContainerRef;
```

Are there any differences(possible issues) between the 2 approaches or any reason as why I should not use the one that requires less code and effort?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you're still trying to solve this but I've been able to get the ViewContainerRef with a directive like this:

```
@ViewChild(AdDirective, {static: true, read: ViewContainerRef}) target: ViewContainerRef;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the Directive you will get vcref only for the first occurrence of the Directive.
If you want vcRef for multiple locations in the Dom , then @viewchild() will be useful.